# Android - SQLite no such column, passed columns are ignored

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-insert

**ANSWER: String fields require ' ' single quotes around them**

I keep getting the message "no such column: value (code 1)" without understanding why.

I am trying to store persons with indexes so I can uniquely identify them and retrieve more complex data that doesn't need to be queried as json, for which I use Gson to convert to and from Json from an object.

**Edited the create query to show a functioning UNIQUE function. [Here you can find more information about ON CONFLICT keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)**

```
//Creation query
private static final String CREATE_PERSON_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    "+PERSON_TABLE_NAME+" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstname VARCHAR, lastname VARCHAR,
    zipcode VARCHAR, birthdate VARCHAR, json VARCHAR,
    UNIQUE(lastname, zipcode, birthdate) ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

//Insert or replace query execution
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "+PERSON_TABLE_NAME+"
(firstname, lastname, zipcode, birthdate, json) VALUES 
("+person.getFirstname()+","+person.getLastName()+","+person.getZipcode()+",
'"+person.getBirthdate+"','"+person.getLifestoryJson()+"')");
```

Stacktrace

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Hank (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE INTO person (firstname, 
lastname, zipcode, birthdate, json) VALUES (Hank,Hairy,8888HH,'06-01-1966','{"events":"[]","comments":[],"storyList":[],"favoriteFoods":"cheddar","peperoni":"lasagna"}')
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
```

I've been staring and comparing with tutorials for hours now, I'm just not seeing what is going wrong. It appears that for some reason the columns I pass are ignored and the values are used as columns instead. Any help or explanation as to what can cause this error is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings need to be wrapped with quotes:

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "+PERSON_TABLE_NAME+"
(firstname, lastname, zipcode, birthdate, json) VALUES 
('"+person.getFirstname()+"','"+person.getLastName()+"','"+person.getZipcode()+",
'"+person.getBirthdate+"','"+person.getLifestoryJson()+"')");
```

Somehow you did wrap the date, the lifestory, but not the firstname, lastname and the zipcode.

Comment: Even better if you bind the parameters by using the **?** placeholder.

Comment: @DerGolem true, that would be more readable. However I didn't feel like re-writting it all for the OP :)

Comment: Ah yes I wrapped those because they have a lot of whitespaces in them, I'll try it now and get back to you asap!

Comment: Additionally, since you are already calling getWritableDatabase(), it might be easier to use the insert() or insertOrThrow() or insertWithOnConflict() methods.

Comment: It appears the main problem was indeed the single quotes, I wasn't aware that I needed them on everything! @Der Golem As for making it cleaner, should I put the query in a separate String and use `table_name(field1=?, field2=?) or how would that even work. If you could point me to a tutorial that'd be great, since I've mimicked the ones I found so far. @crn14 I looked at insert and replace, does insertWithOnConflict behave like the INSERT OR REPLACE? I have a grand total of 5 hours of SQLite experience so don't be afraid to talk to me like I don't understand, chances are I probably don't.

Comment: @G_V quick google search [returned this](http://androidituts.com/android-sqlite-database-insert-example/). Not the best one but the code looks fine. Just search in page for `insert(`.

Comment: @G_V: You don't need the single quotes `on everything`. Only on **string fields**. To pass the bound parameters, you have to pass a string array with the values (see the overloads of the `rawQuery()` and `execSQL()` methods).

Comment: @DerGolem [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])) suggest **not** using `execSQL` for insertion.

Comment: @user3249477 **Totally false**. It doesn't say anything like that.

Comment: @DerGolem I must be drunk, but check the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @user3249477 Yes, I think you are. It says: `It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert` Which literally means that the `execSQL()` **does not return the number of the affected rows**, so you are **encouraged** to use the `insert()` method (which I really **piss on**).

Comment: @DerGolem lol. Piss as much as you want, I still think insert methods are the way to go. `execSQL` provides no error checking whatsoever. But hey, that's my opinion :)

Comment: @user3249477 For a seasoned developer as I am, seeing the complete SQL string means control. I check my commands in a separate tool, on a separate db copy. And I use **transactions**, to manage problems (all db updates committed or all db updates rejected). Which is really the way to go.

Comment: Right now I'm looking into using cleaner code with value insertion by passing both the query and the values separately. I have no idea what I'm doing but it's all fascinating.

Comment: @G_V `I have no idea what I'm doing` This is both `fascinating` and `confusing`. And even `potentially dangerous`.

Comment: You're telling me that SQLite is vulnerable to injection by doing it the "pretty" way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this has anything to do with your problem, but for SQLite I believe the data types allowed are:

INTEGER, TEXT, BLOB, REAL, and NUMERIC

so your create table statement *might* be causing some issues.

here is a different create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE 'person_table_name' (
    'id'            INTEGER,
    'first_name'    TEXT,
    'last_name'     TEXT,
    'zipcode'       TEXT,
    'birthdate'     TEXT,
    'json'          TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

your create unique index maybe can change to:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX 
person_unique 
ON 
person_table_name (first_name, last_name, zipcode, birthdate);
```

your insert or replace into statement can maybe change to:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO 
person_table_name (first_name, last_name, zipcode, birthdate, json) 
VALUES (
    'Hank', 
    'Hairy',
    '8888HH',
    '06-01-1966',
    '{"events":"[]","comments":[],"storyList":[],"favoriteFoods":"cheddar","peperoni":"lasagna"}'
);
```

I used "DB Browser for SQLite" (small program to create db and test sqlite statements etc.)

all the above statements executed successfully.

**I think for your exact situation you need to change the following for your specific statement:**

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " +
PERSON_TABLE_NAME + "(firstname, lastname, zipcode, birthdate, json) +
VALUES ('" + person.getFirstname() + "','" + person.getLastName() + "','" + person.getZipcode() + "','" + person.getBirthdate + "','" + person.getLifestoryJson() + "')");
```

it appears you don't have ' (single quote) around the person.getFirstName() and person.getLAstName() method calls

Comment: Thank you for your very well written answer, I used http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html and it was indeed the single quotes.